# Spark Hive Warehouse Connector Dependency issues

Tags: maven, apache-spark, hive, hdp

So I am trying to enhance my Spark application in Scala 2.11 to read data from HDInsight (HDP) using the Hive Warehouse Connector.
The problem is that for whatever reason I am not able to import any version of the dependency required to perform queries from Spark on Hive in HDP 3+ from Maven Central:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.hortonworks.hive/hive-warehouse-connector?repo=hortonworks-releases

Any suggestions for workarounds?
Thanks.